# A simple Laplace transformation problem

Tags: calculus

Could someone please help me with my misunderstanding here?

Here's the question:

***"A mass M is attached to a spring of stiffness $\omega^2M$ and is set in motion at t=0 by an impulsive force P.
The equation of motion is:
$M\ddot{x} + M \omega^2x = P.\delta(t)$
Obtain an expression for x in terms of t."***

(Where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta function)

Here's my solution which agrees with the answer given in the book:

Taking Laplace transforms of both sides gives:

$Ms^2\bar{x} - Msx_0 - Mx_1 + M\omega^2\bar{x} = P$

Now, substituting in the conditions $x_0=0$ and $x_1=0$ gives:

$\bar{x} = \frac{P}{M(s^2+\omega^2)} = \frac{P}{M}(\frac{1}{s^2+\omega^2}) = \frac{P}{M\omega}*(\frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2})$

Which is now in a standard form and so taking inverse Laplace transformations gives:

$x = \frac{P}{m\omega}sin(\omega t)$

This is the book answer.

BUT here is my misunderstanding:

If I differentiate this answer I get:

$\dot{x}=\frac{P}{M}cos(\omega t)$

and substituting t = 0 in this gives:

$x_1 = \frac{P}{M}$

BUT in order to derive the equation of motion I assumed that $x_1=0$

Where am I misunderstanding?

Thanks,
Mitch.